# iOS correct way (memory management) for a method to return a value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, memory-management

If I have a class named Foo and I have this function `+ getIds` that should return ids. Would the correct signature of `+ getIds` look like this:

```
+ (NSArray *)getIds {

    NSMutableArray *ids = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];

    return ids;
}
```

What I'm wondering is that if I should use autorelease on `*ids`? There is no other way I assume? I can't do `[ids release]` after the return statement right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send *autorelease* message along with *alloc, init* messages. You can also do, `return [ids autorelease];` *Note: You should not do both at the same time* ;-)

You can not return `[id release]`, because `release` method itself returns nothing.

Comment: Okay. But is it possible in the method to instead of using autorelease to `[ids retain]` and then later calling the method `NSArray *ids = [Foo getIds]; // Do something with ids // [ids release];`

Comment: @Peter Warbo, No. The best way is to `autorelease` the `ids` in the `getIds` method, and you should `retain` the returned value from where you call that method, like, `NSArray *ids = [[Foo getIds] retain];`

Comment: What could happen if I don't retain it like you suggested? Figured it out myself. If I call retain on it then I'm responsible of releasing the object later. Otherwise it will be taken care of by the `autorelease`

Comment: @Peter Warbo, Exactly. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The typically-correct memory management for returned objects is to have the called method set it as an autoreleased object, *except* when the method name contains "copy", "new" or "alloc".  In those cases (copy/new/alloc), the returned object is retained, and the caller owns it (i.e. the caller is responsible for making sure they are released).

The code you wrote in the question will do the correct thing - it will return an autoreleased object.

When the caller gets the `NSArray` back, they can use the object as much as they like, and if they don't need the object in future calls, then they don't need to do any extra memory management.  At the end of the run loop, the `NSArray` will be released, which is the desired behavior.  If the caller *does* need the object to live longer, then they have to call retain on it (or something equivalent to that, such as calling something else that calls retain on it), and then they take the responsibility to call release on it later.

Useful stuff:

- [Apple's iOS memory management guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html)
- [My personal memory management guidelines (shorter, more biased)](http://bynomial.com/blog/?p=65)
- [Understanding run loops](http://bynomial.com/blog/?p=15)

Also, this will all go away when ARC (automatic reference counting, in iOS 5) becomes the norm.

Answer (score 0):

You *are* already autoreleasing the array, so calling `autorelease` a second time would be an error that might result in a crash. The fact that you can't do a `release` after the return (you've left the function by then) is one of the reasons `autorelease` exists.

About whether the method should return an autoreleased as opposed to a retained object: Only methods that start with `alloc` or `new` or contain `copy` (as in `mutableCopy`) shall return retained objects. All other method shall return autoreleased objects.

Comment: I know. What I'm wondering is that if I can return the value any other way without autoreleasing it (like i.e `[ids release]`)

Comment: But the `NSMutableArray` is sent an `alloc` message. Shouldn't I be able to use retain then?

Comment: No, your method needs to return an autoreleased object, i.e. an object where the *relative* retain count is 0. You first allocated it (+1), now you need to autorelease it (-1). In other words: you must ensure that the array is cleaned up, even if the caller doesn't use the array.